# javascript: what is the script for "rateapp" link in windows store apps?

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

i am currently developing an windows store app on the platform of JavaScript, I have added a button in the app bar.

If the button is clicked, it should be directly navigated to the "Rate and Review" page of my app in store. Kindly share the javascript code for mt html code.

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="appBar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="">
        <button 
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" 
            data-win-options="{id:'rateapp',label:'Rate App',icon:'admin',
                section:'selection',tooltip:'Rate this app'}">
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no effert has been made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be solving your problem:

```
document.getElementById("rateapp").addEventListener("click", function () { 
window.open("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=[your-package-name]")
});
```

Place the above code in, find

```
    args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () { //place the code//
    });
```